# What's the better way to export a DataGridView in C# to any document (other than MS Excel)?

Tags: c#, datagridview, export

I've an application where I populate DataGridView with the records. I also provide an option in my app to store (or save) DataGrid for reference use.

Here, I would like to go for a document where I can provide an table like view to store the records in order (as it was present in DataGrid). But the problem here is, the machine where i save will not have MS Office in it. *(as MS Excel would always be one of the better ways to export from Datagrid)*

Is there a way to handle this better?
What document to which, I can export the Datagrid? If so, could you pls guide in exporting from datagrid possibly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you will after provide  to the user a tool for reading that data or not.

There are a bunch of solutions, like:

- `CSV` files: good point on this is that are small *relatively* files (plain text data), but you will need provide a *reader* for it, in most cases.
- `SqliteStorage` it's not human readable file,like `csv`, but much more scallable (it's a database) and compact like `csv` file.
- `xml` : wouldn't choose this for middle/big data, cause it's relatively big and you will need provide a reader for it by the way.

These are a couple of options. I'm pretty sure you will get some others too.

Comment: seems like all the above cannot bring a tabular format for the data I export. Pls let know if any other document effectively or else should I have to write a Txt file presenting each and every data in order?

Comment: Choose a `csv` library for  `c#`. They are usually suport a way of specifying delimeter. So you can instead of use `,` use a `tab`.